# ArrayList program not working as desired

Tags: java, arraylist

The code is not working as desired. Console keeps asking for values and never stops.

```
package com.java.collections;

import java.util.*;

public class ArrayList_2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<String>();
        readList(arrayList);
        displayList(arrayList);
    }

    private static void displayList(ArrayList<String> arrayList) {

        for(int i=0;i<arrayList.size();i++){
            System.out.println(arrayList.get(i));
        }

    }

    private static ArrayList<String> readList(ArrayList<String> list) {

        @SuppressWarnings("resource")

        Scanner obj = new Scanner(System.in);

        while(obj.hasNext()){
            String item = obj.next();
            list.add(item);
        }
        return list;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would change up your `while` loop in your `readList` method, like this:

```
Scanner obj = new Scanner(System.in);

String item = "";

//*priming read*
item = obj.nextLine();

while(!item.equals("-0"))
{
  list.add(item);

  //*update read*
  item = obj.nextLine();
} //end while
```

This way the loop is checking for a sentinel value that would be contained in `item`.

Comment: Will try for sure. But I don't understand why my code is not working.

Comment: Let me explain better, `hasNext` returns true if the Scanner, `obj` in your case, has another token in its input. So even entering nothing but an empty string will return true. Your loop does not really have a sentinel value to stop the loop. In my code I provided one, `-0`.

Comment: Couldn't get it to work. I understood what you said though. Thanks a lot! Is there another way to code this right? Please help.

Comment: Ok. What IDE are you using? The input is still not stopping?

Comment: The input stops for me when I enter `-0`. I use NetBeans

Comment: Thanks a lot, I think I got the idea now!

Comment: You're welcome. Let us know if you need any more help.

Comment: does the hasNext() method return true when I enter nothing and click enter?

Comment: Are you using it with a `JTextField`? An empty string, `""` would make `hasNext()` return true.

Comment: No, I'm just trying to learn ArrayLists. Okay, looks like I have to change the while loop condition.

Comment: Ok, but yes a condition change is needed.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is not working because it is stuck in the while loop. You have no break condition in it. Try replacing it with this one:

```
    while (obj.hasNext()) {
        String item = obj.next();
        if (item.equals("stop")) {
            break;
        }
        // otherwise do stuff here...
    }
    obj.close();
```

When you enter "stop" the loop will terminate. Do not forget to close your scanner instance.

Comment: Thanks, I got the idea now!

Comment: does the hasNext() method return true when I enter nothing and click enter?

Comment: Why don't you just test it? Just add the following inside your loop, e.g.: System.out.println("hasNext() was true.");

Answer (score 0):

Your program does not stop and keeps on asking for more values because there is no code which tells the program to stop :).

You can add some condition which tells the code to stop accepting input, eg. when user has entered 5 words as below (see the commented lines):

```
 private static void readList(ArrayList<String> list) {

    @SuppressWarnings("resource")
    int start = 1; // start count
    int end = 5;   // end count
    Scanner obj = new Scanner(System.in);

    while(obj.hasNext() && start<=end){ // <- Note the condition!
        String item = obj.next();
        list.add(item);
        start++; // Keep a count.
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks, I got the idea now!

Comment: does the hasNext() method return true when I enter nothing and click enter?

Comment: I believe it will return true since you are still entering an empty input. You can debug your code and check the documentation to verify this.